# htaccess question about Rewrite and Redirect

Tags: apache2

I've been banging my head against a wall trying to do what should be fairly straightforward in .htaccess but without success.  I'm hoping someone can help me.

I need to achieve 3 basic things:
1) Redirect my domain www.sample.com to www.sample.com/subdir1/cgi-bin/
2) If the page is NULL or index.html, load the script home.php
3) Hide the sub-directories "subdir1/cgi-bin"

For example, when someone goes to www.sample.com, they would see:
www.sample.com/home.php

but

The server would actually be reading www.sample.com/subdir1/cgi-bin/home.php

Thank you!

Comment: "If the page is NULL or index.html [...]", what do you mean by that? what should it attempt to load first before loading `home.php`? Should every single script be loaded from a folder under "www.sample.com/subdir1/cgi-bin/" ? Do you have access to modify a virtual host configuration, Because your requirements are better served by changing the DirectoryRoot directive.

Comment: What I meant was if someone types in the domain name without the filename "index.html" after it.  That's all I meant by NULL.   The server will default to load index.html.   I can do a basic redirect, but I can't seem to get rid of the sub directories.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a .htaccess file that looks like this :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*

# Turn on the RewriteEngine
RewriteEngine On

# When accessing root
DirectoryIndex subdir1/cgi-bin/home.php

# Rules
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . subdir1/cgi-bin/home.php
```

Then you have to be sure that your Apache server authorizes the rewriting. To achieve this, edit the file */etc/apache2/apache2.conf*. In this file, find the Directory you use and change "AllowOverride None" by "AllowOverride all". Here is an example :

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

After that, activate the rewriting module of Apache by running :

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

At the end, restart Apache :

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: I don't have root access.  I'm on a share.   The Rewrite rule seems to be working because I was able to create a rewrite rule that redirected ^$ to /subdir1/subdir2   But that's all I could do.

Comment: I tested it.  It *ALMOST* works.  For some reason I lose all the CSS formatting, and it doesn't show in the URL www.sample.com/home.php.   I have 2 directories:   /6/cgi-bin and /6/htdocs    It appears that when I execute the code above, the Rewrite causes all my relative paths in my script to break.   I wasn't expecting to have to rewrite my code in order to accomplish this task.